# empty output + errors if i move the .println line anywhere else

Tags: java, file

i have to do a student averages program and i can't get the output to print out. if i move the .println line outside of the while loop, i get "cannot find symbol" errors.

i think it might not be printing because i already read the file once, and i'm trying to read it again to figure out the averages. how can i make this work?

contents of my file:

Agnes 56 82 95 100 68 52

Bufford 87 92 97 100 96 85 93 77 98 86

Julie 99 100 100 89 96 100 92 99 68

Alice 40 36 85 16 0 22 72

Bobby 100 98 92 86 88

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EZD_studentAvgs
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
  {
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("EZD_gradebook.txt"));

  int max = -1;
  String fr[] = new String[100];
  System.out.println("The input file:\n");

  while(sf.hasNext())
  {
    max++;
    fr[max] = sf.nextLine();
    System.out.println(fr[max]);
  }
  //System.out.println("max: " + max);
  System.out.println("");

  System.out.println("\nThe output:\n");

  while(sf.hasNextLine())
  {
    Scanner ga = new Scanner(sf.nextLine());

    String student = ga.next();
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(ga.hasNextInt())
    {
      sum = sum + sf.nextInt();
      count++;
    }
    System.out.println(student + ", average: " + (sum/count));
  }



  sf.close();
  }
 }
```

Comment: You read lines into `fr`, but then you don't do anything with them.  Your other `while` does something different; it reads a string and then a series of ints.

Comment: *symbol not found* - I suggest reading a book on java, particularly around scope of variables, before trying File I/O.

Comment: sorry, i meant "cannot find symbol" if that makes any difference.???just typed the error out wrong

Comment: like it was said above, read more. Just a simple explanation that calling upon variables that you declare in loops can only be called within loops. calling a variable outside it's area of scope is like calling upon a variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You read the lines into `fr` until `sf.hasNext()` returns false. You never reset `sf`, so it would be logical to think that, when you reach `sf.hasNextLine()`, it will be false also.

Instead of reading the lines again, just run scans on the strings you've already read in; in other words, it looks like you can loop through the strings in `fr` from 0 to `max` in place of the loop currently based on `sf.hasNextLine()`.